# How do I make Ubuntu ask for a password when I'm trying to mount another H.D.D

Tags: mount

Some data that I don't want other people to see it, how do I make Ubuntu ask for a password when I'm trying to mount another H.D.D?

Comment: Hmmm, unity desktop uses udisksctl as backend , so i assume that's what should be either disabled or modified. But i can't investigate this completely right now